# Gnome Evolution: Focus top-most item, not the last item in the e-mail list when it starts?

Tags: gnome, evolution

When it first starts, it focuses on the last-viewed item in the e-mail list. So, to see the newest e-mail first, I have to scroll all the way up. Can I make Evolution focus on the top-most item in the list when it starts, like other e-mail applications do?